# how to resize bottomsheet when keyboard is opened?

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard, bottom-sheet

I am using one BottomSheet which I have defined as STATE_EXPANDED.I have 3 edittext in bottomsheet.I did force edittext when bottomsheet opened.When bottomsheet is opened keyboard is opened at the same time.so far no problem.im using android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" in Linearlayout.When bottomsheet is opened, an image like this occurs;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVIGq.jpg)

but my goal is here;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMofK.jpg)

I mean, when edittext is selected when botttomsheet is opened, I want the space at the bottom to be as much as the keyboard for the menu to appear.

here are my codes;

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="?attr/bottombarcolor"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="?attr/textcolor"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
        app:iconGravity="start"
        app:iconTint="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:backgroundTint="?attr/bottombarcolor"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/dropdownlist"
        app:hintTextColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="?attr/bottombarcolor"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColorHint="?attr/textcolor"
        app:boxCollapsedPaddingTop="2dp">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/filled_exposed_dropdown"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sdfsdfsfsg"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:fontFamily="@font/regularopensans"
            android:textColor="?attr/textcolor" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>




    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_apply"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="?attr/textcolor"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_check_black_24dp"
        app:iconGravity="end"
        app:iconTint="?attr/colorPrimary"
        />

</LinearLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorPrimary"/>



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:text="@string/newtask"
    android:textColor="?attr/textcolor"
    android:fontFamily="@font/regularopensans"/>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/outlinedTfNew"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/entertask"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    app:hintTextColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:textColorHint="?attr/textcolor"
    app:boxStrokeColor="?attr/textcolor"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_mic_black_24dp"
    app:endIconTint="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:startIconTint="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/txteditNew"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="?attr/textcolor"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lightopensans" />
    <requestFocus />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:backgroundTint="?attr/textcolor"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/taskcompdate"
    android:textColor="?attr/textcolor"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:fontFamily="@font/regularopensans"/>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/outlinedTfComp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/nodate"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    app:hintTextColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:textColorHint="?attr/textcolor"
    app:boxStrokeColor="?attr/textcolor"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:startIconTint="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_today_black_24dp"
    app:endIconTint="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="?attr/textcolor"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lightopensans"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:backgroundTint="?attr/textcolor"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/tasktime"
    android:textColor="?attr/textcolor"
    android:fontFamily="@font/regularopensans"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/outlinedTfTime"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/notime"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    app:hintTextColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:textColorHint="?attr/textcolor"
    app:boxStrokeColor="?attr/textcolor"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
    app:endIconTint="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_access_time_black_24dp"
    app:startIconTint="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="?attr/textcolor"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lightopensans" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:backgroundTint="?attr/textcolor"
    />
```

When I click on the bottom edittext, the situation I want occurs.I want this to happen when the first edittext is selected.

Comment: can you show code of listeners( editText) in your activity/fragment?

Comment: added xml side. i didnt anything activity side.